# Java: tricky replace String

Tags: java, string

I am having an issue with inserting a string into a String[] array. I have the following String:

```
12343,"Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan",lol,"HI",ZF-32,"TZ,45,38"
```

or for example this string:

```
"Another String",44,33,"TZ,38",ok
```

This is only one of millions of Strings my application is to seep through. The issue is the seperator in this case is the `,` character. However it is sometimes baked into one of the field.

Now as you can see `"Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan"` has that character, however this belongs to the field and is not to be counted as a seperator.

I have come up with the following code, I am stuck.

```
String before = "12343,\"Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan\",DH1,\"HI\",ZF-32,\"TZ,45,38\"";
System.out.println(before);

int first = before.indexOf("\"");

if(first != -1) {
    Boolean firstTime = true;
    int firstPos = 0;
    int secondPos = 0;

    for (int i = -1; (i = before.indexOf("\"", i + 1)) != -1; ) {
        if(firstTime) {
            firstPos = i;
            firstTime = false;
        } else {
            secondPos = i;
            System.out.println(before.substring(firstPos+1, secondPos));
            firstTime = true;
        }
    }           
}
```

This results in:

```
12343,"Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan",lol,"HI",ZF-32,"TZ,45,38"
Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan
HI
TZ,45,38
```

I would like a String[] array to look like this:

```
String[] array = {"12343", "Den Haag, Willem de Zwijgerlaan", "lol", "HI", "ZF-32", "TZ,45,38"};
```

Comment: Maybe you should just look for the delimiter \

Comment: The answer is the same as for any similar question: **don't use regex for non-regular Strings**. Use a CSV parser. That's what they're for.

Comment: Or arrange for the data to be shipped as JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks unfortunetly that is out of my reach :(

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you! You answered my question, using opencsv now and it's doing the job well! I did not recognize that this was a CSV dump, always learning new things

Comment: @KarlMorrison: good going!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a regular expression here; you have a non-regular string. You can use a CSV (comma-separated value) parser which should split the string up into its constituent parts. One option is to use [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Another option is to parse the string out manually according to a grammar:

```
<line>              ::= <element> {',' <element> }
<element>           ::= '"' <contents> '"'
<contents>          ::= { <character> | <escaped-character> }
<character>         ::= *  //any old character
<escaped-character> ::= '\' <character>
```

But really, it would be easier to use a CSV parser.

Comment: You say this isn't a regular language. I beg to differ. For instance, the regex `"([^"]|\\")*"|[^,]+` might do it, although it's unclear exactly what the parsing rules are. And not that I'd advise it, of course.

Comment: Ended up using opencsv!